# Why can't I chmod these files that I could earlier?

Tags: permissions, find, chmod

I was trying to add execute permissions to sh files in a folder. For that I mistakenly used:

`find . -print0 -iname '*.sh' | xargs -0 chmod -v 744`

and the output was :

```
mode of `.' changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0744 (rwxr--r--)
mode of `./codis.sh' changed from 0644 (rw-r--r--) to 0744 (rwxr--r--)
mode of `./ne fil.sw' changed from 0644 (rw-r--r--) to 0744 (rwxr--r--)
mode of `./.whois1.sh.swo' changed from 0644 (rw-r--r--) to 0744 (rwxr--r--)
mode of `./new file' changed from 0644 (rw-r--r--) to 0744 (rwxr--r--)
mode of `./ezik.sh' changed from 0644 (rw-r--r--) to 0744 (rwxr--r--)
mode of `./.whois1.sh.swp' changed from 0600 (rw-------) to 0744 (rwxr--r--)
mode of `./whois1.sh' retained as 0744 (rwxr--r--)
```

I now know that the correct usage for the  find part was

`find .  -iname '*.sh' -print0`

So I created another find like so:

`find . \! -iname '*.sh'  -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 600`

so that I may set back the permissions for non-sh files (yes, I see that some files have 644 perms, not 600 but it does not matter now). The output for this command is :

```
chmod: cannot access `./ne fil.sw': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access `./.whois1.sh.swo': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access `./new file': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access `./.whois1.sh.swp': Permission denied
```

I used `sudo` too but still nothing...

I see I do not understand permissons properly... If I understand correctly I need `x` permisions  for directory `direc` too in order to execute commands in said directory.

Comment: Are you owner of current directory?

Comment: in between the command that changed permissions and the command that outputs permissions denied  i have not run any permission-altering commands. for the directory in which i am working the permissions are: `drw------- 2 joee joee 4096 Jun 24 02:06 scripts` ; i opened the terminal as joee and tried sudo too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `find` cmd also finds the current directory "`.`". The rights of this directory will then be set to `600` and therefore you'll lose the rights to touch the files within this directory.

So `cd ..`, `chmod 700` said directory and then run your reverting `find`, which now excludes the current directory, like this:

```
find . \! -path . \! -iname '*.sh' -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 600
```

Comment: well, that makes sense ... i just noticed, like you said, that  `find . \! -iname '*.sh' ` includes  "`.`" in the results too...

Comment: Don't forget to close your questions so they don't show up in the section `unanswered` :).

Comment: At least in the GNU world this can be done with `-mindepth 1`, too.

Comment: @polym the command does not work... it sets perms to 600 for *.sh files... the negation does not work. I am looking to set permissions for files other that .sh

Comment: forgot to add an \!, try it  now :)

Comment: yep, works now. the mindepth 1 argument also works. thanks folks